# JQuery sequential function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing problem executing below code

```
$("#btnFCSubmit").click(function () {
function1();
function2();

$.ajax({
                        url: "/SaveFormsConfigData?DT=" + Date.now(),
                        cache: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { selectedData: JSON.stringify(selectedData), loginURLSuffix: $('#ddProgramList').val() },
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $('#divResult').html('Forms saved successfully');                              

 $('#gridFormsConfig').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                        LoadValidationElement(msg);
                        $("#tblNewForm").hide();
                        $("#divEditForms").show();
                        isTicketRegistered = false;
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        $('#divResult').html("an error occurred: " + error);

                    }
                });
}

function function1() {
    $("#divTicketDetail").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        title: "Please associate a Ticket",
        height: 200,
        width: 320,
        buttons: {
            "Associate": function () {
                $('#txtDisplayTicket').val($('#txtTicketId').val());
                                    $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $("body").css({ overflow: 'hidden' })
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function2()
{
 //somevalidation for value of txtDisplayTicket
}
```

The ajax function gets called even before function1() and function2() complete their execution. I want to take values from popup of function1 and post it as ajax request value.
function2() has few items which are dependent on function1() execution, where function1() shows a popup and take input and pass it to function2.

I tried $.when().then, it did not worked. May be I made some mistake.

Comment: it's impossible to help you unless you post your code. you've been around long enough to know that...

Comment: you're missing the closing ` )`

Comment: If `function1` returns a result, you need to assign that to a variable and then pass it as a parameter to `function2`.

Comment: Does `function1` perform any asychronous actions, like waiting for the user to fill in a dialog?

Comment: Javascript **is** sequential, `function2()` will always run after `function1()`. Your description makes it sound like what you need is to add `function2()` as a callback to your input.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/f83josm4/

Comment: @Barmar no function1 does not make any async call, but $("#btnFCSubmit").click() has async call which should be called after function1 and function2 executes.

Comment: @Ravia `.dialog()` is asynchronous. It returns immediately, but the DOM isn't updated until the user clicks on the `Associate` button.

Comment: @Barmar Before they click the associate button the async function is getting called

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `function2()` in the function associated with the `Associate` button in the dialog. Otherwise, you'll call `function2()` before the user has interacted with the dialog.

```
function function1() {
    $("#divTicketDetail").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        title: "Please associate a Ticket",
        height: 200,
        width: 320,
        buttons: {
            "Associate": function () {
                $('#txtDisplayTicket').val($('#txtTicketId').val());
                $(this).dialog('close');
                function2();
            }
        },
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $("body").css({ overflow: 'hidden' })
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What about ajax call(), which is getting called even before function1() & function2() executes.

Comment: I don't see anything in the AJAX call that depends on `function1` or `function2`. If it does, then it should be done from inside `function2`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing `)`  also is it a input type ="submit" , maybe adding a preventDefault() aswell, you say function 2 is dependant on function 1, call function2 from function 1 then

```js
$("#btnFCSubmit").click(function () {
function1();

});

function function1(){alert('function 1');function2();}
function function2(){alert('function 2');}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnFCSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: What if you have ajax call after function1(); statement, it gets called immediately without waiting for function1() to finish.